How to write code to resize window displaying an HTML Document?
I am working on a developing a demo displaying a html document and some other things. For this I need to place a window displaying an html document in the top right corner of my screen taking up a quarter of the screen.
I have tried doing this using batch files through internet explorer but it did not work for my html file specifically. I have also tried using WinForms to achieve this, but because WinForms uses Internet Explorer as well, that didn't work. I tried writing a batch file to resize an edge window/chrome window, but neither worked. I suspect my JavaScript code is not compatible with Internet Explorer. For security reasons, I am not allowed to use AutoHotKey and probably cannot use a browser extension. Does anyone know what I can do to resize this window displaying my html file? Do I need to change my JavaScript to accommodate internet explorer or can I do something else?
For reference here is my HTML, CSS, and Javascript and PowerShell code in that order:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LAD Touchscreen Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="image.png" alt="Interactive Image" id="interactiveImage">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="clickable" data-value="1" style="top: 0%; left: 0%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="2" style="top: 0%; left: 25%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="3" style="top: 0%; left: 50%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="4" style="top: 25%; left: 0%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="5" style="top: 25%; left: 25%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="6" style="top: 25%; left: 50%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="7" style="top: 50%; left: 0%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="8" style="top: 50%; left: 25%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="9" style="top: 50%; left: 50%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="0" style="top: 75%; left: 25%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="CLEAR" style="top: 75%; left: 0%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="ALT" style="top: 0%; left: 75%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="HDG" style="top: 25%; left: 75%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="VOR" style="top: 50%; left: 75%;"></div>
            <div class="clickable" data-value="SPD" style="top: 75%; left: 75%;"></div>
            <div id="alt-display" class="display" style="top: 10%; left: 75%;">00000</div>
            <div id="hdg-display" class="display" style="top: 35%; left: 75%;">00000</div>
            <div id="vor-display" class="display" style="top: 60%; left: 75%;">00000</div>
            <div id="spd-display" class="display" style="top: 85%; left: 75%;">00000</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: green;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', Courier, monospace;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* Adjust this ratio based on your image's aspect ratio */
    margin: auto;
}

#interactiveImage {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.clickable {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.clickable:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.display {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    pointer-events: none;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var selectedOption = null;
    var displays = {
        ALT: document.getElementById('alt-display'),
        HDG: document.getElementById('hdg-display'),
        VOR: document.getElementById('vor-display'),
        SPD: document.getElementById('spd-display')
    };

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', (function (element) {
            return function () {
                var value = element.getAttribute('data-value');
                if (value === 'CLEAR') {
                    if (selectedOption) {
                        displays[selectedOption].innerText = '00000';
                    }
                } else if (value === 'ALT' || value === 'HDG' || value === 'VOR' || value === 'SPD') {
                    selectedOption = value;
                } else if (selectedOption) {
                    var currentValue = displays[selectedOption].innerText;
                    var newValue = currentValue === '00000' ? value : currentValue + value;
                    displays[selectedOption].innerText = newValue.slice(-5); // keep only the last 5 digits
                }
            };
        })(elements[i]));
    }
});

@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass - 
File get_resolution.ps1') do (
set SCREEN_WIDTH=%%a
set SCREEN_HEIGHT=%%b
)

set /a WINDOW_WIDTH=%SCREEN_WIDTH% / 2
set /a WINDOW_HEIGHT=%SCREEN_HEIGHT% / 2
set POS_X=0
set POS_Y=0

echo Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") > 
set_window.vbs
echo IE.Visible = True >> set_window.vbs
echo IE.Navigate "index.html" >> set_window.vbs
echo WScript.Sleep 2000 >> set_window.vbs
echo IE.Left = %POS_X% >> set_window.vbs
echo IE.Top = %POS_Y% >> set_window.vbs
echo IE.Width = %WINDOW_WIDTH% >> set_window.vbs
echo IE.Height = %WINDOW_HEIGHT% >> set_window.vbs

cscript set_window.vbs
del set_window.vbs


on any internet browsers, the positioning and sizing of navigation windows are the prerogatives of the (human) user exclusively.

Which version of IE are you using? The code I am seeing here is compatible with IE11.

WinForms doesn't use the WebBrowser Control anymore. It has been deprecated a while go. It's not even present in any .NET version of WinForms. It uses WebView2 instead (Edge Chromium)

@Jimi Thank you your comment helped me solve the issue!
